# Solving a double recursion relation for computing a derivative

Tags: real-analysis, recurrence-relations

I came across a double recursion relation I want to solve

$a_{m,k}=a_{m+1,k-1}-a_{m,k-1}$ for $m,k\geq 0$.

Context

The first derivative of a function satisfies $f^{(1)}(\lambda)=f(\lambda+1)-f(\lambda)$. I want to find a formula for all its derivatives i.e. 
$f^{(k)}(\lambda)=?$. So I set $a_{m,k}=f^{(k)}(\lambda+m)$ and I want to compute $a_{0,k}$.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can prove by induction on $n$ that

$$f^{(n)}(\lambda)=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k(-1)^kf(\lambda+n-k)\;.$$

This is clear for $n=0$, and

$$\begin{align*}
f^{(n+1)}(\lambda)&=f^{(n)}(\lambda+1)-f^{(n)}(\lambda)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k(-1)^kf(\lambda+1+n-k)-\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k(-1)^kf(\lambda+n-k)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k(-1)^kf(\lambda+1+n-k)+\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\binom{n}{k-1}(-1)^kf(\lambda+n+1-k)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\left(\binom{n}k+\binom{n}{k-1}\right)(-1)^kf(\lambda+n+1-k)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}k(-1)^kf(\lambda+n+1-k)\;.
\end{align*}$$